# What's the proper way to create a ViewModel for uploading an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My View Model looks like this:

```
public class UploadImageForm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
}
```

But it renders as this:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/E4sRP.png" />
```

When the `.cshtml` looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ImageMeta</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

How do I get it to display an a standard `<input type="file">` upload control instead? I'm not sure how to customize the "editor" or if it will even upload correctly.

---

Discovered these `Html.IdFor` and `.NameFor` helpers through intellisense. Now I can do:

```
<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.Image)" type="file" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Image)"/>
```

Which I quite like because it avoids magic strings to create the mapping. Still trying to figure out if there's an Html helper for the full input, and if not, how to create one.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if there is a razor html helper for file input (upload). But you can use plain html input syntax.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ImageFile", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) {
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
}
```

**Edit:** ImageFileController action would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    string name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    // HINT: Im uploading to App data folder!
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Also, there are some razor helpers in *Microsoft.Web.Helpers* namespace which you can find from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers.fileupload).

Comment: What about for the ID and Name? What do I set them to so they map properly?

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you pick the file you need to upload and submit, controller action will receive as "Action-Name(HttpPostedFileBase file)".

Comment: I've defined my action as `public ActionResult Create(UploadImageForm imageForm)` and it seems to be filling in the proper property. Why would I want to separate out the file when I can encapsulate it nicely in my View Model?

Comment: Yes Mark, it looks nice, but if this serves the purpose why wrap it with another type? It will couple another type to the app, yes?

Comment: Huh? The `UploadImageForm` is needed to encapsulate the rest of the form variables anyway, how is this "coupling another type"?

Comment: Ok. got your point, I was under the assumption that you have only the file. Alternatively, there is another library that might help you. Have you checked Microsoft.Web.Helpers namespace which has a razor html helper (I have no experience on this namespace tho)?